# Nexmo SDK update Nuget package .net

Tags: .net, nuget, vonage

I want to update nexmo SDK from 3.0.1 to 3.1.1 which gives me the following error.

**

> Failed to add reference to 'System.Runtime.Extensions'. Please make
>   sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

**

Please help me solve my problem. I am using package manager console to install nexmo SDK.